# Retagging: Getting the Group Together

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

Tag proposal number 3:

Change [group-assignment](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-assignment) to [group-work](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-work)

Upvote if you agree, downvote if you disagree, or answer if there are additional considerations.

Comment: I thought that group *assignment* was about partitioning students to groups. But then, sometimes I miss the obvious.

Answer (score 3):

[group-work](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-work) is potentially larger than [group-assignments](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/group-assignments) in scope while including it. I don't see the need to choose between assignments and other "work", such as in-class exercises and such, when tagging a question. The question itself can delineate the conditions between them. From an educational perspective I think the dynamics and results are sufficiently similar to tag all such questions together.

Comment: My point exactly.